# Как убрать два нуля на ценнике в магазине

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

пробовал менять с Decimal на Int.
Игрался с Decimal но все четно...
почему то именно строка price не реагирует на изменения и выдает ценник с двумя нулями после запятой.
вот скрин из базы данных.
[image: скрин из базы данных]

вот скрин из магазина
[image: скрин из магазина]

вот функция которая отвечает за это как я понял)

```
public function formatCurrency($price, $currency = null)
{
    $price = preg_replace(['/(,)/', '/[^0-9.-]/'], $price);

    $currency = ($currency) ? new Zend_Currency($currency) : Core_Model_Language::getCurrentCurrency();

    return $currency->toCurrency($price);
}
```

Comment: если тип поля int тоже выводил с двумя нолями, то скорее всего сама цена выводится с помощью функции `number_format()`

Comment: public function formatCurrency($price, $currency = null)
    {
        $price = preg_replace(['/(,)/', '/[^0-9.-]/'], $price);

        $currency = ($currency) ? new Zend_Currency($currency) : Core_Model_Language::getCurrentCurrency();

        return $currency->toCurrency($price);
    }

Comment: `return rtrim($currency->toCurrency($price),',0')` или, чтоб с копеек не удалять последний ноль, `return str_replace(',00','',$currency->toCurrency($price))`

Comment: благодарю вассс

Answer (score 0):

Вы используйте Zend Framewerk, в нем есть функция для работы с валютами, свой аналог number_format, если вам ненужно форматирование, то просто уберите код преобразования из функции:

```
public function formatCurrency($price, $currency = null)
{
    return number_format($price);
}
```

Более подробно можно ознакомится тут https://framework.zend.com/manual/1.0/en/zend.currency.useage.html

Comment: спасибо за информацию

Comment: но почему то мне не помогло -( все как было ...